# docker, container ports and iptables

Tags: docker, firewall, iptables

I have inserted an iptables rule to block access to my containers from the internet (according to the official docker docs), but now my containers cannot access the internet either.

I run a container on a dedicated server like this:

```
docker run --name mycontainer --network network1 -d -p 10000:80 someImage
```

I can access that container from my **home network**...:

```
telnet servername.com 10000
```

... even though I have limited access using `ufw`:

```
ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
...
```

It makes no mention of port 10000, and I initially denied all incoming ports.

According to the docs at https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ when starting a container with `-p`, docker will automatically expose the port through the firewall by manipulating iptables, using rules which are evaluated before `ufw` rules.

Those docs then go on to suggest blocking incoming requests like this, in the section titled "*Restrict connections **to** the Docker host*":

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eno ! -s 192.168.1.1 -j DROP
```

I got the interface name by running `route`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         static-ip-182-1 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-ef37f7b34afa
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-979cf8868fcd
182.133.43.627  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eno
```

It works, I can no longer telnet onto port 10000.  (surprisingly I didn't need to reload / restart anything).

Unfortunately, I can no longer access the internet from inside a container. The dedicated server can still ping google.com, but my container cannot:

```
docker exec mycontainer ping google.com

ping: unknown host
```

That was working before inserting the iptables rule, but doesn't work any more.

Question 1: what do I have to change in ufw / iptables so that my containers can again access the internet (outgoing), but so that I still cannot access my container from the internet (incoming)?

Question 2: what do I have to change in the iptables rule so that it survives a reboot, because I noticed that after a reboot, I can again telnet to port 10000.

UPDATE:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME         DRIVER    SCOPE
a1e2c7cdbc65   bridge       bridge    local
218e121af9cd   host         host      local
979cf8868fcd   network1     bridge    local
cee02cfd1dba   none         null      local
ef37f7b34afa   network2     bridge    local
```

I noticed that `/etc/resolv.conf` is different depending upon whether I check on a container inside a network or one with the default network:

```
docker run -it --rm --network network1 alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0

docker run -it --rm alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 80.237.128.56
nameserver 80.237.128.57
```

Those two nameservers are the ones that my dedicated server uses.

```
ufw show raw | grep DROP
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      br-ef37f7b34afa  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      br-979cf8868fcd  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   14262  1201304 DROP       all  --  eno    *      !127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
     173    37057 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     427    35720 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
       0        0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
       0        0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
       0        0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate INVALID
       0        0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 rt type:0
       0        0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                
       0        0 DROP       all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
```

a little more detail around those drops and docker generally:

```
Chain DOCKER (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       2      120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-979cf8868fcd br-979cf8868fcd  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:3306
       1       60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-ef37f7b34afa br-ef37f7b34afa  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:18088
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-979cf8868fcd br-979cf8868fcd  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-ef37f7b34afa br-ef37f7b34afa  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:3306

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      19     1164 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   14533  1228562 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-ef37f7b34afa !br-ef37f7b34afa  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
     168    14646 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-979cf8868fcd !br-979cf8868fcd  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   25893  4430799 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      br-ef37f7b34afa  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      br-979cf8868fcd  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   14720  1244372 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   14465  1218356 DROP       all  --  eno2   *      !127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
   25893  4430799 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

```
ufw show raw | grep REJECT # contains ip addresses from fail2ban
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.202.169.48        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      25     1904 REJECT     all  --  *      *       112.85.42.128        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      19     1664 REJECT     all  --  *      *       61.177.172.89        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      23     1884 REJECT     all  --  *      *       112.85.42.74         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      21     1764 REJECT     all  --  *      *       112.85.42.15         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      23     1884 REJECT     all  --  *      *       112.85.42.87         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      22     1748 REJECT     all  --  *      *       122.194.229.54       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      19     1644 REJECT     all  --  *      *       122.194.229.45       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      22     1844 REJECT     all  --  *      *       218.92.0.221         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
      18     1104 REJECT     all  --  *      *       112.85.42.88         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
       0        0 REJECT     all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
```

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/a/933803/505063